# nodejs form with multiple inputs having same name

Tags: html, node.js, post, express

Let me thank you ahead first :)

I am using express with node. I have a form of type

```
<form>
    <div id=row-1>
        <input name=item></input>
        <input name=price></input>
    </div>
    <div id=row-2>
        <input name=item></input>
        <input name=price></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is I have multiple inputs with the same name, and ideally in req.body, I would want my data to be of the form:

```
[
    {
        item: item1,
        price: price1
    },
    {
        item: item2,
        price: price2
    }
]
```

But, when I post the form data, this is what I get:

```
{
    item: [item1, item2],
    price: [price1, price2]
}
```

Is there something that I might be missing?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this ?

```
var data; // this is what you got.
var i;
var newObjectArray = [];
for(i= 0; i<object.item.length; i++)
    newObjectArray.push({item: data.item[i], price: data.price[i]});
```

Comment: but this is what i am doing to go around the problem right now :) I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: You got to take care of this in the front end.
If you can't, look into "underscore js" node package and you'll find cleaner ways to do what my code does.